# Get current track info and media controls

Tags: android, wear-os, google-music

In Android Wear Google play music seems to integrate somehow generic music controls, in Android 5 lollipop this can be done using `MediaSession`, however in pre Lollipop you can't.
You can use `MedicaControllerCompat` but seems this does not work, do nothing on pre Lollipop.
So how can i make a Music Media contoller? Android wear (or Google music mini) can skip next or prev track from spotify for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RemoteController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html) was the older equivalent to the new `MediaController` API, but was only made public in Android 4.4 (Kitkat) and has a number of onerous requirements for non-system apps (such as being an enabled [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)), hence why it is now deprecated along with the older [RemoteControlClient API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) that apps like Spotify use.

TL/DR: non-public before Android 4.4, public but hard to use on Android 4.4, and the totally new API on Android 5.

Comment: Thanks to this comment i found a thread on XDA doing what you said :) http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48702254#post48702254